# AJAX request return JSON with properties instead of entire string as one value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have an AJAX request with JSON dataType shown here:

JS:

```
function checkForNewPosts() {

    var lastCustomerNewsID = <?php echo $customers_news[0]['id']; ?>;

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.example.com/check_for_new_posts.php",
        method: "post",
        data:{
            lastCustomerNewsID: lastCustomerNewsID,
        },
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data)
        {
            $.each(data, function( key, value ) {
                console.log(key + ": " + value);
                $('#wall_posts').prepend(value);
            });
        }
    });

}
```

PHP:

```
if ($_POST) {

    $lastCustomerNewsID = $_POST['lastCustomerNewsID'];

    $new_posts = sw::shared()->customers_news->getNewForWall($lastCustomerNewsID);

    if ($new_posts) {

        foreach ($new_posts as $new_post) {

            $content = "<div class='wall_post'>";
            $content .= $new_post['message'];
            $content .= "</div>";

            $last_id = $new_post['id'];

            $testyme[] = json_encode(
                array(
                    "content" => $content,
                    "last_id" => $last_id
                ),
                JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES
            );

        }

    }

    echo json_encode($testyme);

}
```

I'd like to access the properties individually but it is returning the "value" as the entire string instead of broken up into "content" and "last_id" properties.

Example output with existing code:

```
109: {"content":"<div class='wall_post'></div>","last_id":"367"}
110: {"content":"<div class='wall_post'>testttt</div>","last_id":"366"}
```

How can I return the JSON so that it is properly access by property?

example:

```
 $.each(data.last_id, function( key, value ) {
      $('#wall_posts').prepend(Id: ${value.last_id}, Content: ${value.content}<br>);
 });
```

JSON Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'content' => '<div class=\'wall_post\'>Check it out here: <a href=\'https://www.example.com/events/trymeguy/\'>https://www.example.com/events/trymeguy/</a></div>',
'last_id' => '476',
```

),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `json_encode()` for each array element. Just encode the final result. So the line in the loop should be:

```
            $testyme[] = array(
                "content" => $content,
                "last_id" => $last_id
            );
```

In the JS that processes the response, you need to extract the properties.

```
$('#wall_posts').prepend(value);
```

should be something like:

```
$('#wall_posts').prepend(`Id: ${value.last_id}, Content: ${value.content}<br>`);
```

Comment: thanks! its now returning as Object Object. When I try to point to data.last_id it returns undefined. I tried stringifying the data

Comment: `value` is an object, that's what you get when you try to print it. I've shown how to extract the properties and print them separately.

Comment: $.each(data.last_id, function( key, value ) {
    $('#wall_posts').prepend(`Id: ${value.last_id}, Content: ${value.content}<br>`);
   }); --------- data.last_id returns nothing, even after I stringify

Comment: I can't see any reason for that.

Comment: You're missing the backticks in the code you posted in the question.

Comment: thats just the way it came out here on SO. there's something else going on where data.last_id doesn't return anything

Comment: I updated the OP to show how the JSON that is output converts to a PHP array to show you the structure

Comment: I finally figured it out. Thanks for walking me through